# Set Excel Fill Based on a (Variable) Cell

Tags: excel, vba

My main issue right now is that I want to fill a range of excel cells (let's say K5 through K35) based on what is in cells I5-35. This number corresponds to the RGB number (out of 255).

I'm just getting into VBA so I would appreciate any input here. This is the code that excel is throwing me a 424 - Object required error.

```
Sub Colors()
Dim index As Integer
index = 5

While index <= 35
   colorVar = Worksheets("Pivot").Cells(index, "I").Value
   cellActive = "K" & index
   cellActive.Interior.Color = RGB(255, colorVar, colorVar)
   index = index + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

When I had it running for one individual cell (without the while loop) it was able to do it it perfectly, but I am having trouble making it go down the list.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it's a pretty quick fix to achieve what you are doing. Below is what I came up with:

```
Sub Colors()
Dim index As Integer
index = 5

While index <= 35
    colorVar = Worksheets("Pivot").Cells(index, "I").Value
    Set cellActive = Range("K" & index)
    cellActive.Interior.Color = RGB(255, colorVar, colorVar)
    index = index + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Your problem is not setting `cellActive` as a Range.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Excel is telling you that it has no object to run the .Interior.Color on. You are only giving it text, not a column reference. If you convert your code for the first run through in the loop, it'll look like this:

```
K5.Interior.Color = RGB(255, colorVar, colorVar)
```

What you want it to look like is

```
Range("K5").Interior.Color = RGB(255, colorVar, colorVar)
```

To do that, you will need to change that line of code as follows:

```
Range(cellActive).Interior.Color = RGB(255, colorVar, colorVar)
```